Need help optimizing Python code to compute the bifurcation point $ B_3 $ of the logistic map (Experimental Math)
I’ve been reading a book on experimental mathematics, Experimental Mathematics in Action by David Bailey et al. (AK Peters/CRC Press, 2007), and I came across an algorithm for computing a high-precision value of $ B_3 $. The book provides the following description:


It is fairly easy to see that all of these $ B $ constants are algebraic numbers, but the bounds one obtains on the degree are often rather large, and thus not very useful. Thus one may consider using PSLQ or some other integer relation algorithm to discover their minimal polynomials.
A highly accurate numerical value of $ B_3 $, for instance, can be obtained using a relatively straightforward search scheme. Let $ f_8(r, x) $ be the eight-times iterated evaluation of $ r x(1-x) $, and let $ g_8(r, x)=f_8(r, x)-x $. Imagine a three-dimensional graph, where $ r $ ranges from left to right and $ x $ ranges from bottom to top (as in Figure 2.2), and where $ g_8(r, x) $ is plotted in the vertical (out-of-plane) dimension. Given some initial $ r $ slightly less than $ B_3 $, we compute a "comb" of function values at $ n $ evenly spaced $ x $ values (with spacing $ h_x $) near the limit of the iteration $ x_{n+1}=f_8\left(r, x_n\right) $. In our implementation, we use $ n=12 $, and we start with $ r=3.544 $, $ x=0.364 $, $ h_r=10^{-4} $, and $ h_x=5 \times 10^{-4} $. With this construction, the comb has $ n / 2 $ negative function values, followed by $ n / 2 $ positive function values. We then increment $ r $ by $ h_r $ and re-evaluate the "comb," continuing in this fashion until two sign changes are observed among the $ n $ function values of the "comb." This means that a bifurcation occurred just prior to the current value of $ r $, so we restore $ r $ to its previous value (by subtracting $ h_r $), reduce $ h_r $, say by a factor of four, and also reduce the $ h_x $ roughly by a factor of 2.5. We continue in this fashion, moving the value of $ r $ and its associated "comb" back and forth near the bifurcation point with progressively smaller intervals $ h_r $. The center of the comb in the $ x $ direction must be adjusted periodically to ensure that $ n / 2 $ negative function values are followed by $ n / 2 $ positive function values, and the spacing parameter $ h_x $ must be adjusted as well to ensure that two sign changes are disclosed when this occurs. We quit when the smallest of the $ n $ function values is within two or three orders of magnitude of the "epsilon" of the arithmetic (e.g., for 2000-digit working precision, "epsilon" is $ 10^{-2000} $). The final value of $ r $ is then the desired value $ B_3 $, accurate to within a tolerance given by the final value of $ r_h $. With 2000-digit working precision, our implementation of this scheme finds $ B_3 $ to 1330-digit accuracy in about five minutes on a 2004-era computer. The first hundred digits are as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 B_3= & 3.54409035955192285361596598660480454058309984544457367545 \\
 & 78125303058429428588630122562585664248917999626 \ldots
 \end{aligned} $$


I tried writing Python code to replicate this result, but my implementation is incredibly slow, taking way longer than the "five minutes" described in the book. Here's the code I wrote:
import mpmath
from mpmath import mp

# Set working precision to 2000 digits
mp.dps = 2000

# Define the function f(r, x) = r * x * (1 - x)
def f(r, x):
    return r * x * (1 - x)

# Define the 8-times iterated function f_8(r, x)
def f_8(r, x):
    for _ in range(8):
        x = f(r, x)
    return x

# Define the function g_8(r, x) = f_8(r, x) - x
def g_8(r, x):
    return f_8(r, x) - x

# Implement the comb technique to find bifurcation points
def find_b3(initial_r, initial_x, h_r, h_x, n):
    r = initial_r
    x = initial_x

    # Define tolerance and set up an iteration loop
    tolerance = mp.mpf('1e-2000')
    
    while True:
        comb_values = []
        x_vals = [x + i * h_x for i in range(n)]

        # Evaluate the comb (g_8 values for different x)
        for xi in x_vals:
            comb_values.append(g_8(r, xi))

        # Check for sign changes in the comb
        sign_changes = 0
        for i in range(1, len(comb_values)):
            if comb_values[i-1] * comb_values[i] < 0:
                sign_changes += 1
        
        # If two sign changes are found, refine r and h_r, h_x
        if sign_changes >= 2:
            h_r /= 4
            h_x /= 2.5
        else:
            r += h_r
        
        # Check if the smallest comb value is within the desired tolerance
        if min(abs(val) for val in comb_values) < tolerance:
            break
    
    return r

# Initial parameters
initial_r = mp.mpf('3.544')
initial_x = mp.mpf('0.364')
h_r = mp.mpf('1e-4')
h_x = mp.mpf('5e-4')
n = 12

# Call the function to find B3
B3 = find_b3(initial_r, initial_x, h_r, h_x, n)

# Print the result
print(f"B_3 = {B3}")

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for optimizing this code to speed it up. Did I misunderstand something in the algorithm, or is there a more efficient way to compute this?
Thanks for your help!

I suspect what makes it slow is that you implement f_8 in the brutest possible way. With a bit of work this should have an explicit expression.

Hi Mark, # Set working precision to 2000 digits from the beginning might be overdone. I do not know Python, but in REXX I would increase precision according to the progress of the iteration.

You compute all 12 samples before the check for two sign changes. Instead you could start to check after the 2nd sample and in case there are two sign changes omit the remaining computations of current "comb".

The center of the comb in the x direction must be adjusted periodically -- can't see this in your program. BTW, if you run it only for 20 digits of $B_3$, does it show at least some tendency to the correct value?

@m-stgt: I apologize, but I accidentally clicked on "Accept" from my phone. My request is still open because the code isn't working, and I'm having trouble implementing the suggestions you gave me. That's why I started a bounty.

@Mark -- honestly, I tried to reproduce the procedure in REXX, without success as of yet. I fail to detect properly the bifurcation. It seems that eight iterations for a sample point are insufficient to indicate it. Thus the description is either wrong or incomplete or too flimsy for me to grasp.

Unfortunately, your code will $\color{red}{\text{NOT}}$ calculate the desired Logistic Map Bifurcation $(B_3)$, because it is not implementing the mathematical concept explained in the paper. The code is missing the following $\color{red}{\text{CRUCIAL}}$ implementation mentioned in the paper: 

"The center of the comb in the $x$ direction must be adjusted periodically to ensure that $n/2 $ negative function values are followed by $n/2$ positive function values". Meaning, we have to chose were to but the initial value of $x$ (in what index inside the array). Every-time we calculate the array, we have to check if the chosen position of the initial value is reflecting this adjustment. And if not, we have to shift it, and re-calc. 
"The spacing parameter $h_x$ must be adjusted as well to ensure that two sign changes are disclosed when this occurs". Meaning, we have to define a scaling factor for $h_x$, and we have to adjusted (as needed) while progressing. Honestly, similar scaling factor has to be defined for $h_r$ as well. 
"We continue in this fashion, moving the value of $r$ and its associated "comb" back and forth". Meaning, sometimes the algorithm may pass some increment of $r$ for some given values of $n\,,x_0\,,h_x$. Nevertheless, we have to be carful and try to change this values (smartly) to double check before accepting such increment of $r$. 

Let us explain the algorithm first, Try the following Mathematica Code: 
comb = ConstantArray[0.0, 12];
d = 0.0001; s = 0.0005; r = 3.544; x = 0.364;
For[i = 1, i <= 12, i++,
  xm = x - ((i - 5)*s);  (* Centering "x" *)
  xn = xm;
  For[n = 1, n <= 8, n++, xn = r*xn*(1 - xn)];
  comb[[i]] = xn - xm;
  ];
MatrixForm[comb]

The output should be:
$$
\frac{\text{for}\,\,r=3.544\color{blue}{0}}{
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{-}\,0.000089557\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000051828\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000026800\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000011839\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000004144\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000000749\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000001471\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000005803\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000015687\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000034715\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000066622\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000115285
\end{pmatrix}}
\qquad
\frac{\text{for}\,\,r=3.544\color{red}{1}}{
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{-}\,0.000080122\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000043745\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000020255\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000007020\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000001239\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000000052\\
\color{red}{-}\,0.000000021\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000001827\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000009040\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000025207\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000054070\\
\color{blue}{+}\,0.000099504
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

Notice that in the code, we put the initial value of $x$ at index $n/2$ (not at $1$). Once we increment $r$ by $h_r$, and re-evaluate, we end-up with double signs in the array. Hence, the Main Loop of the algorithm is to calculate like-wise symmetric arrays. 
A smart move will be to notice that No Need to store any value of the computation (neither $f_8$ nor $g_8$, or even "comb" nor "sign"). the main two required values are (Sign Changing Count) and (Sign Changing Index). 
the expected resulting array shall fall in on of four categories: 
$\qquad\color{blue}{\text{A. Signs do not change at all -> Shift/Re-Calc}}$. 
$\qquad\color{blue}{\text{B. Signs change one time, Not at the center -> Shift}}$. 
$\qquad\color{green}{\text{C. Signs change one time, at the center -> Pass/Increse}}$. 
$\qquad\color{red}{\text{D. Signs change more than one time -> Failed/Reset}}$. 

Finally, below is a sample Mathematica code with Output, with my apology for non-optimizing, because optimizing $\,n,\,h_r,\,h_x\,$ and their scaling factors require a lot (lot!) of try and error effort and time. Best Wishes. 
(* BEGIN *)
(* Set: Number of Iteratations, Number of X-Intervals, Tolerance *)
intIterat = 8; intPoints = 120; valEpsilon = 10^-10;
(* Declare: Signs Array *)
arySign = ConstantArray[0.0, intPoints];
(* Initiate: Delta of R, Setp of X, Initial-R, Initial-X *)
valScaleD = 4; valScaleS = 2.5;
valD = 0.0001; valS = 0.0005;
valR = 3.544; valX = 0.364;
(* Align: the Center Point, where Sign Change should happen *)
intCenterPoint = intPoints/2;

(* === === ===  Main Loop  === === === *)
While[valD > valEpsilon, {
   (* Set a Flag to repeat the calculation whenever:
      1. Signs do not change at all
      2. Signs change more than one time 
      3. Signs change one time but not at the center  *)
   bolRepeatCalc = True;
   While[bolRepeatCalc, {
     (* Loop over Xn *)
     For[i = 1, i <= intPoints, i++, {
       (* Center the current "best" X at the center of the X's *)
       valXm = valX - ((i - intCenterPoint)*valS);
       valXn = valXm;
       (* Iterate Xn Eight Times and register the sign *)
       (* NB: No Need to register the values, 
       all what we need is the signs *)
       For[n = 1, n <= intIterat, n++, valXn = valR*valXn*(1 - valXn)];
       arySign[[i]] = If[valXn < valXm, -1, +1];
       }];
     (* Calc number of changing signs, 
     and the position of the first change *)
     (* Use the position of the first change to catch the "best" X *)
     (* and to re-center the X's *)
     intChangeSignPoint = 0; intChangeSignCount = 0;
     For[i = 1, i < intPoints, i++, {
       Which[arySign[[i]] + arySign[[i + 1]] == 0, {
          
          intChangeSignPoint = 
           If[intChangeSignPoint == 0, i, intChangeSignPoint];
          intChangeSignCount++;
          }];
       }];
     (* After calculating "ChangeSignPoint" and "ChangeSignCount", *)
     (* Everything is ready to handle the result cases *)
     
     (* Case "1": ChangeSignCount=0 -> the system is unclear, 
     try to move current X and Re-Calc *)
     Which[intChangeSignCount == 0, {
       valX = valX + valS;
       }];
     (* Case "2": ChangeSignCount=1 -> 
     the system is PASS unless the changing is not at the center *)
     Which[intChangeSignCount == 1, {
       (* If the changing is not at the center, re-align it, and re-
       calc *)
       Which[(intChangeSignPoint < (intPoints*0.49)) ||
         (intChangeSignPoint > (intPoints*0.51)) , {
         
         intCenterPoint = 
           intPoints/2 + (intCenterPoint - intChangeSignPoint);
         }];
       (* If the changing is  at the center, 
       register all values then increase R *)
       Which[(intChangeSignPoint >= (intPoints*0.49)) &&
         (intChangeSignPoint <= (intPoints*0.51)) , {
         Print[
          "r = ", NumberForm[valR + 10^-14, 15], " - ",
          "x = ", NumberForm[valX + 10^-14, 15], " - ",
          "d = ", valD, " - ",
          "s = ", valS
          ];
         bolRepeatCalc = False;
         valS = valS/valScaleS; valScaleS = valScaleS/1.1;
         valX = valX + ((intCenterPoint - intCenterPoint)*valS);
         valR = valR + valD;
         }];
       }];
     (* Case "3": ChangeSignCount>1 -> 
     Reset R to the old "good" value, *)
     (* reduce its increment, and try again *)
     Which[intChangeSignCount > 1, {
       valR = valR - valD;
       valD = valD/valScaleD; valScaleD = valScaleD/1.01;
       valR = valR + valD;
       }];
     }];
   }];
(* END *)

r = 3.54400000000001 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 0.00010000000 - s = 0.00050000000
r = 3.54402500000001 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 0.00002500000 - s = 0.00020000000
r = 3.54405000000001 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 0.00002500000 - s = 0.00008800000
r = 3.54407500000001 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 0.00002500000 - s = 0.00004259200
r = 3.54408131250001 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 6.31250*10^-6 - s = 0.00002267600
r = 3.54408762500001 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 6.31250*10^-6 - s = 0.00001328000
r = 3.54408923484532 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 1.60985*10^-6 - s = 8.55500*10^-6
r = 3.54408964950163 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 4.14656*10^-7 - s = 6.06228*10^-6
r = 3.54409006415794 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 4.14656*10^-7 - s = 4.72547*10^-6
r = 3.54409017203120 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 1.07873*10^-7 - s = 4.05179*10^-6
r = 3.54409027990445 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 1.07873*10^-7 - s = 3.82156*10^-6
r = 3.54409030824842 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 2.83440*10^-8 - s = 3.96486*10^-6
r = 3.54409033659239 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 2.83440*10^-8 - s = 4.52488*10^-6
r = 3.54409034411431 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 5.68041*10^-6
r = 3.54409035163623 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 7.84412*10^-6
r = 3.54409035915816 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 0.00001191520
r = 3.54409036668008 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 0.00001990910
r = 3.54409037420200 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 0.00003659270
r = 3.54409038172393 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 0.00007398280
r = 3.54409038924585 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 0.00016453500
r = 3.54409039676777 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.52192*10^-9 - s = 0.00040251300


Hello Hazem! The comb has $12$ teeth -- which is the one in the middle? No. $5$?
For[i = 1, i <= 12, i++,   xm = x - ((i - 5)*s);  (* Centering "x" *)

@m-stgt, When I demonstrated the first entry constructed by the paper, I choose to plug-in the value at index $5$ so the system will result-in a symmetric array. Nevertheless, as mentioned in my explanation and implemented in the sample code { intCenterPoint = intPoints/2 + (intCenterPoint - intChangeSignPoint); }, you should always have a similar adjusting procedure to re-align the resulting array to have $n/2$ negative/positive values.

@HazemOrabi: Thank you! Your code works, producing the same results posted in your solution, even if after the first iterations my computer ends in long running...

@Mark: Glad it was helpful. Nevertheless, I'd recommend: 1) an optimization to the scaling factors ${,\text{ScaleD},,&,,\text{ScaleS},}$ is required as progress, and 2) the  code explanation in the sample code is a step-by-step algorithm that could be use to write a program with your preferable programming language. Good Luck.

You'll need to test these suggestions yourself to see how much they help, but:

@KurtG. already suggested rewriting f_8 to use a shorter for loop with a higher-order polynomial. Admittedly coding a degree-$256$ polynomial g_8 may be error-prone, but even halving the for loop size would help. You should also consider how you efficiently evaluate a polynomial. Since your problem is polynomial in r too, you may need to go beyond Wikipedia. You also might benefit from "inlining" f_8, viz.

def g_8(r, x):
    y = x
    # This for loop hasn't been rewritten with any of the other advice yet
    for _ in range(8):
        y *= r*(1-y)
    return y-x


I'd recommend making some code more declarative, e.g. comb_values = [g_8(r, x+i*h_x) for i in range(n)] or, if you add import numpy as np as an early line, comb_values = g_8(r, x+h_x*np.arange(n)). Incidentally, converting lists into arrays, using numba decorators etc. could work wonders (rewriting everything in C would help a lot - in fact, that may be what Bailey et al had in mind, not Python - but this is the next best thing).

Your sign_changes takes O(len(comb_values)) time to evaluate even though only a O(1) condition on its size matters. (You need to spend linear time assembling the list for the tolerance check later, so unforutnately the speedup will be at most a O(1) factor.) You can cut this short by adding a break in your second for loop (but I'm not sure whether that would break the while, so if I were you I'd refactor it out into a function returning sign_values).

Computers multiply faster than they divide, so change


h_r /= 4
h_x /= 2.5

to
h_r *= 0.25
h_x *= 0.4

I think there might be an efficient halving trick for numbers, since they're stored in binary, in which case you could use that on h_r twice.
That's about all I can suggest for the present code. I suspect the fastest way to compute many digits of a root of a function is with a quadratically convergent algorithm such as the Newton–Raphson method, not interval bifurcation as in this example.

Here is a python code which is quick, but I'm not sure how to terminate the loop:
import mpmath
from mpmath import mp

mp.dps = 1000

intIterat = 8
intPoints = 120
valEpsilon = mp.mpf('1e-10')  # Precision for stopping the loop
convergence_threshold = mp.mpf('1e-14')  # Stop when r changes by less than this amount

arySign = [0] * intPoints

valScaleD = 4
valScaleS = 2.5
valD = mp.mpf('0.0001')
valS = mp.mpf('0.0005')
valR = mp.mpf('3.544')
valX = mp.mpf('0.364')

intCenterPoint = intPoints // 2

def iterate_x(r, x, iterations):
    for _ in range(iterations):
        x = r * x * (1 - x)
    return x

def print_formatted_output(valR, valX, valD, valS):
    print(f"r = {mp.nstr(valR, 14)} - x = {mp.nstr(valX, 14)} - d = {mp.nstr(valD, 10)} - s = {mp.nstr(valS, 10)}")

prev_r = valR
iteration_counter = 0
max_iterations = 5000  # Set a maximum number of iterations

while valD > valEpsilon and iteration_counter < max_iterations:
    bolRepeatCalc = True
    while bolRepeatCalc:
        intChangeSignPoint = 0
        intChangeSignCount = 0

        for i in range(1, intPoints + 1):
            # Center the current "best" X at the center of the X's
            valXm = valX - ((i - intCenterPoint) * valS)
            valXn = iterate_x(valR, valXm, intIterat)
            arySign[i - 1] = -1 if valXn < valXm else 1

        for i in range(1, intPoints):
            if arySign[i - 1] + arySign[i] == 0:
                intChangeSignPoint = intChangeSignPoint or i
                intChangeSignCount += 1

        # Case 1: No Sign Changes move current X and recalculate
        if intChangeSignCount == 0:
            valX += valS
        
        # Case 2: One Sign Change check if it’s at the center
        elif intChangeSignCount == 1:
            if not (intPoints * 0.49 <= intChangeSignPoint <= intPoints * 0.51):
                # Re-align center point and re-calculate
                intCenterPoint = intPoints // 2 + (intCenterPoint - intChangeSignPoint)
            else:
                # If at center, register values and increment R
                print_formatted_output(valR + mp.mpf('1e-14'), valX + mp.mpf('1e-14'), valD, valS)
                bolRepeatCalc = False
                valS /= valScaleS
                valScaleS /= 1.1
                valX += ((intCenterPoint - intCenterPoint) * valS)
                valR += valD
        
        # Case 3: More than one sign change reset R and try again
        else:
            valR -= valD
            valD /= valScaleD
            valScaleD /= 1.01
            valR += valD
    
    # Stopping condition: Not sure why it's not stopping
    if abs(prev_r - valR) < convergence_threshold:
        print("Converged. Final value of r:", valR)
        break
    prev_r = valR
    iteration_counter += 1

print(f"Final value of r: {valR}, after {iteration_counter} iterations.")


r = 3.544 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 0.0001 - s = 0.0005
r = 3.544025 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 2.5e-5 - s = 0.0002
r = 3.54405 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 2.5e-5 - s = 8.8e-5
r = 3.544075 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 2.5e-5 - s = 4.2592e-5
r = 3.5440813125 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 6.3125e-6 - s = 2.26759808e-5
r = 3.544087625 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 6.3125e-6 - s = 1.32799614e-5
r = 3.5440892348453 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 1.609845313e-6 - s = 8.555004251e-6
r = 3.5440896495016 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 4.146563088e-7 - s = 6.062284754e-6
r = 3.5440900641579 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 4.146563088e-7 - s = 4.725471186e-6
r = 3.5440901720312 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 1.078732544e-7 - s = 4.051786863e-6
r = 3.5440902799044 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 1.078732544e-7 - s = 3.821560591e-6
r = 3.5440903082484 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 2.834396864e-8 - s = 3.964857588e-6
r = 3.5440903365924 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 2.834396864e-8 - s = 4.524880568e-6
r = 3.5440903441143 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 5.680405431e-6
r = 3.5440903516362 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 7.844120062e-6
r = 3.5440903591582 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 1.191521315e-5
r = 3.5440903666801 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 1.990912093e-5
r = 3.544090374202 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 3.659274914e-5
r = 3.5440903817239 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 7.398278528e-5
r = 3.5440903892459 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 0.0001645352675
r = 3.5440903967678 - x = 0.36400000000001 - d = 7.521923464e-9 - s = 0.0004025130923


Please consider adding in more information as to why your code addresses the question or helps make significant progress towards the desired outcome as stated in the question.
